# Crossing Symmetry between tree-level diagrams of $e^+ e^- \rightarrow \mu^+ \mu^-$ and $e^- \mu^- \rightarrow e^- \mu^-$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, scattering-cross-section, s-matrix-theory, leptons

According to Peskin and Schroeder (P&S)'s book, on pp. 156-157, the two processes $e^+ e^- \rightarrow \mu^+ \mu^-$ and $e^- \mu^- \rightarrow e^- \mu^-$ are connected via $s \leftrightarrow t$ crossing symmetry.

I tried to see it but I only found $s, t, u$ (Mandelstam variables) changes as
\begin{align*}
s \rightarrow t \rightarrow u \rightarrow s.
\end{align*}
Indeed I got same scattering matrix element $\mathcal{M}$ (maybe $|\mathcal{M}|^2$), but I think I made some mistakes.

**My thoughts**

At first, I should make particles' momenta explicit:
\begin{align*}
 e^- (p) + e^+ (p') \rightarrow \mu^- (k) + \mu^+(k').
\end{align*}
Then cross $e^+$ as
\begin{align*}
 e^- (p) \rightarrow \mu^- (k) + \mu^+(k') + e^- (-p').
\end{align*}
Again cross $\mu^+$ as
\begin{align*}
  e^- (p) + \mu^-(-k') \rightarrow \mu^- (k) + e^- (-p').
\end{align*}

Hence if we denote initial momenta as $\tilde{p}, \tilde{p}'$ and final momenta $\tilde{k}, \tilde{k}'$respectively, the Mandelstam variables written in this process become
\begin{align}
\tilde{s} = (\tilde{p} + \tilde{p}')^2 = (p - k')^2 = u,\\
\tilde{t} = (\tilde{k} - \tilde{p})^2 = (-p'-p)^2 = s,\\
\tilde{u} = (\tilde{k}' - \tilde{p})^2 = (k-p)^2 = t.
\end{align}

So none of the variables unchanged in this crossing... I guess.

What is wrong this argument?

Notation is based on P&S.
P&S denote initial momenta as $p, p'$, and final momenta $k, k'$. Prime(') distinguishes particle's type this time (on first process: particle/antiparticle, second process: $e^-$ or $\mu^-$).

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct, and P&S may have made a mistake or introduced an inconsistency in their notation—see, for example, [the lectures by Prof. Floerchinger](https://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Efloerchinger/qft1/Lecture24/). However, both the correct and the incorrect substitution lead to the same expression for the spin-averaged squared matrix element, as seen in (5.71) in P&S.